# Failed to download repository information Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: package-management, updates, 13.10, software-center, update-manager

I know that this question has been asked many times but everything I've seen has not helped me.  I'm new to linux.  I'm on 13.10 and I get that message every time I try to update my software sources.  Let me know what other information you need.  Below is the detail under the "Failed to download repository information  Check your Internet connection." message.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 reached end of life on 2015-07-31. Please use a newer version, like 15.10.

Comment: Also, that is not 14.10; that is 13.10, which is an extra year past end of life.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Sauncy (13.10) [is already EOL](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/17/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2014/). [Upgrade it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) to a newer release. If I were you, I'd wait the release of 16.04 LTS, and upgrade to that.